How to dynamically add additional formControls via template outlet?
So, I have the issue that I have a base component that has a form. But I would like to be able to add another field to it. Why? Because I have four pages, with a very similar structure, that differ only in one field at most. I've got a stackblitz that should get the idea across as well. The rendering part is working nice and well.
But to also give a general idea:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `<form
  style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 1rem"
  [formGroup]="form"
>
  <input formControlName="search" type="text" placeholder="Search something" />

  <ng-template
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: form }"
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="seachOptionalField()!"
  ></ng-template>
</form>`,
})
export class BaseFormComponent {
  seachOptionalField = input<TemplateRef<any>>();
  fb = inject(UntypedFormBuilder);
  form = this.fb.group({
    search: this.fb.control(['']),
  });
}

The idea was initially to pass the form via the outlet context, but programmatically adding a control didn't really impact the original form. Also, there was the question on how to apply the rendered (to be used) form control.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, BaseFormComponent],
  template: `
    <app-base-form [seachOptionalField]="searchOptionalField"></app-base-form>
    <ng-template #searchOptionalField let-form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="We just added this" />
    {{form.value | json}}
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class App {}


You need to provide a corresponding formControlName on the new controls, also wrap them on a form element inside the template.
You can also add an extra parameter, which specifies the new form controls configuration on a object which we can destructure into our form group when initializing.
Working example below with stackblitz!
Full Code:
main.ts
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import 'zone.js';
import { BaseFormComponent } from './app/base-form/base-form.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, UntypedFormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, BaseFormComponent, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <app-base-form [seachOptionalField]="searchOptionalField" [extraFormParams]="extraFormParams"></app-base-form>
    <ng-template #searchOptionalField let-form>
      <form [formGroup]="form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="We just added this" formControlName="search2"/>
    </form>
    {{form.value | json}}
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class App {
  fb = inject(UntypedFormBuilder);
  extraFormParams = {
    search2: this.fb.control(['']),
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

base-form.ts
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, TemplateRef, inject, input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  UntypedFormBuilder,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `<form
  style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 1rem"
  [formGroup]="form"
>
  <input formControlName="search" type="text" placeholder="Search something" />

  <ng-template
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: form }"
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="seachOptionalField()!"
  ></ng-template>
</form>`,
})
export class BaseFormComponent {
  seachOptionalField = input<TemplateRef<any>>();
  extraFormParams = input<Object>({});
  fb = inject(UntypedFormBuilder);
  form!: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      search: this.fb.control(['']),
      ...this.extraFormParams(),
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Damn! I had an idea of using the form tag there too, but the idea simply never crossed my mind to provide the controls as an input as well! Sometimes the simpler solutions are the best ones! Thank you SO much!
